# ADF data flow Error 404 - Check request and body

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I setup a pipeline and dataflow in Azure Datafactory.  The purpose is get a token and then get data from an API.  I am getting the token fine. then I set a token variable and pass that token into the data flow.  I'm getting an error in the source data set.

Here is the error message:

> Job failed due to reason: at Source 'srcJSONTdTicketMetrics': Failure to read most recent page request: DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some(), Status code: 404. Please check your request url and body. (url:https://arkanalabs.teamdynamix.com/reports/168,request body: None, request method: GET)

I'm attaching a PDF of the configuration of my pipeline and dataflow with errors.  Also, I'm attaching the Data flow JSON script and pipeline JSON script.

Here is the URL from the API documentation:
`https://arkanalabs.teamdynamix.com/TDWebApi/api/reports/{id}?withData={withData}&dataSortExpression={dataSortExpression}`

Base URL
`https://arkanalabs.teamdynamix.com/TDWebApi/api`

Relative URL
/reports/168?withData=true&dataSortExpression='ID'

I don't know if the error is due to the paramterized token or the format of the URL.

Also, I tested this with a WEB source in a copy activity.  It worked fine, but now I'm using a REST data set in the data flow because I need to flatten.
Here is the pipeline JSON script:

```json
{
    "name": "pl_teamdynamix_get_report",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Token",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.00:10:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "relativeUrl": "/auth/login",
                    "connectVia": {
                        "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
                        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "body": "{\n\nUserName: \"user_name\",\nPassword: \"password\"\n}"
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "ls_web_teamdynamix_dev",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get Report List",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "state": "Inactive",
                "onInactiveMarkAs": "Succeeded",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Token",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.00:10:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "relativeUrl": "/reports",
                    "connectVia": {
                        "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
                        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": {
                            "value": "Bearer @{activity('Get Token').output.Response}",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "ls_web_teamdynamix_dev",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get Report 168 - Ticket Metrics",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "state": "Inactive",
                "onInactiveMarkAs": "Succeeded",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Token",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.05:10:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "relativeUrl": "/reports/168?withData=true&dataSortExpression='ID'",
                    "connectVia": {
                        "referenceName": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime",
                        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
                    },
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        "Authorization": {
                            "value": "Bearer @{activity('Get Token').output.Response}",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "ls_web_teamdynamix_dev",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "df_teamdynamix_get_reports",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set token variable",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.00:10:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "df_teamdynamix_get_reports",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "access_token": {
                                "value": "@variables('token')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "Fine"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set token variable",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Token",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "token",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "Bearer @{activity('Get Token').output.Response}",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "token": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "API"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-12-10T21:30:39Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Here is the data flow JSON script:

```json
{
    "name": "df_teamdynamix_get_reports",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "ds_json_td_ticket_metrics",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "srcJSONTdTicketMetrics"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "ds_sql_td_ticket_metrics",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "SinkSQLTDTicketMetrics"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     access_token as string",
                "}",
                "source(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     httpMethod: 'GET',",
                "     timeout: 30,",
                "     requestInterval: 0,",
                "     headers: ['Authorization' -> ($access_token)],",
                "     paginationRules: ['supportRFC5988' -> 'true'],",
                "     responseFormat: ['type' -> 'json', 'documentForm' -> 'arrayOfDocuments']) ~> srcJSONTdTicketMetrics",
                "srcJSONTdTicketMetrics sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:false,",
                "     truncate:true,",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> SinkSQLTDTicketMetrics"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the format of the URL by adding curly braces, but I got invalid character error.  I also tried different formats of the token.

Comment: This seems to be internal issue. Is it working in Postman?